# Showing that the intersection of two subgroups is a product of subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $U, V$ be subgroups of a group $G$ and $N, M$ be normal subgroups of $U, V$ respectively. Consider the following diagram:
[image]

Every 'node' in the diagram is a subgroup of $G$. We see that if node $A$ is connected to node $B$ by an edge moving upwards, then $A < B$. In addition, I've been told the following statements are also true:

1. The intersection of two downward-sloping line segments is the intersection of the two nodes the segments originate from.
2. The intersection of two upward-sloping line segments is the product of the two nodes the segments originate from.

I've managed to convince myself that statement 1. is true for all but the $(N\cap V)(U\cap M)$ node, i.e I wish to show:
$$ \left( N(U\cap M) \right) \cap \left( (N\cap V)M \right) = (N\cap V)(U\cap M).$$
It's clear that the RHS lies inside the LHS ($N$ contains $N\cap V$ for example), but I haven't been able to show that LHS $\subset$ RHS. My attempt so far has mostly been playing with the definitions to get:

Let $g \in N(U\cap M)$ and assume $g \in (N\cap V)M$, then we can write
$$ g = n u_M = v_N m $$

for $n \in N, u_M \in U\cap M, v_N \in V\cap N, m \in M$. One way to move forward is to find $v_N' \in N\cap V, u_M' \in U\cap M$ such that $g = v_N'u_M'$, although I do not know how to define these elements $u_N', v_M'$. Alternatively, if I could reason that $n$ must lie in $V$ (or $m$ must lie in $U$) then I would also have the result. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to take either of these approaches sufficiently far.

Any recommendations on how I should proceed? Perhaps the normality of $N, M$ in $U, V$ can help since I haven't used those yet?

For context: the diagram and the setting are from pages 20-21 of Lang's Algebra, with the notation changed slightly (he uses $u = N \vartriangleleft U$ and $v = M \vartriangleleft V$), and this is used to prove the Butterfly Lemma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your notation we have $n=v_Nmu_M^{-1}$, where the left hand side is in $N$ and the right hand side is in $V$. Thus $n\in N\cap V$ and $g=nu_M\in(N\cap V)(U\cap M)$.